# $2$ is prime, but $2=(1+i)(1-i)$ is composite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

If $2$ is a prime number, there is a corollary that says that every prime integer is irreducible on the Gaussian integers. But this is a contraction, for $2$ is composed of $(1+i)(1-i)$, and a number that can be composed cannot be irreducible.

How can this be?

I am totally confused. Does anyone propose to assist me?

Comment: Note that $5=(1+2i)(1-2i)$

Comment: $2$ is prime (and irreducible) in $\Bbb Z$, but not in $\Bbb Z[i]$

Comment: But, $ 2\in \Bbb Z  \subseteq \Bbb Z[i]\subseteq \Bbb C$.

Comment: Irreducibility is relative to the system you work in; when you add more numbers to the system, you can create new factors. In this case, the $4n+3$ prime integers are still irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ while the $4n+1$'s are not (and $2$ is not, as you showed in the OP). Showing the $4n+3$'s are irreducible is really simple, showing the $4n+1$'s are not is a little bit more complicated. See https://www.math.umd.edu/~psg/406/gaussianintsols.pdf So it sounds like you have either been misinformed or misunderstood something.

Comment: What is the exact statement of that “corollary that says that every prime integer is irreducible on the Gaussian integers”?

Comment: Why is it a contraction? Or is that a typo?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos. Sorry, isn't Corollary. It is a Lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)

Comment: But that's a lemma about polynomials. What does it have to do with Gaussian integers?

Comment: @FernandoSousa I don't really see how you drew this conclusion from there...

Comment: I thought as follows: If the Norm of an element is a prime integer, then this element is irreducible in the Gaussian integers. However, an element being irreducible does not imply that it is cousin. Therefore, by these two statements, I understood what I wrote.

Comment: In the language of algebraic number theory, if $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, then $\langle p\rangle$ *splits* in the extension $\mathbb{Z}[i] / \mathbb{Z}$.  2 is a special case since the prime factorization $2 = -i (1+i)^2$ has repeated factor, so $\langle 2 \rangle$ is a *ramified prime* of the extension.  (I unfortunately don't quite recall the terminology for $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ where it remains prime in the extension - something along the lines of inert or stationary?)

Comment: @DanielSchepler:  yes, inert

Answer (score 5):

Notice that $5 = \sqrt{5}\sqrt{5}$, so the prime $5$ can be factored in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}].$   "Prime" in this context means "can't be factored in the integers." It doesn't mean you can't add some more numbers to your system and create more factors.

Answer (score 2):

That corollary probably says that every prime $p$ *satisfying* $p\equiv 3\pmod4$ stays prime among the Gauss integers.

Actually, every other primes (so $2$ and primes with $p\equiv1\pmod4$) do factor nontrivially in $\Bbb Z[i]$.